# How to find difference of same column in foreach loop

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, difference

I am take all field in for-each loop and take the difference of each two column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kDUu.png)

The above image 'tech_strt_km' is field name and take the difference of 122-22 and 200-122 how find these difference and store there values in another variyable i am using foreach loop for print these numbers

```
<?php
foreach($pexpn as $row) { 
    echo $row->tech_strt_km;  ?><br>
} ?>
```

Any way to find the difference of same column 
please help me !!

Comment: Please post your field name to display difference with table structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine. We add one to the current key to get the next value so we can subtract it from the current value, then we save these differences in an array `diff` for later usage.

```
$arr = array('22', '122', '200');
$diff = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (!isset($arr[$k + 1])) {
        // if we don't have a next item we are done
        // break from foreach
        break;
    }
    // abs only necessary if we expect negative differences and
    // if we don't want that --- store differences in array
    // for later usage
    $diff[] = abs($arr[$k + 1] - $v);
}
print_r($diff);
```

Comment: @alex first $diff is declare as array and finally the calculation time $diff [ ] why call these two time?

Comment: @Shambu if for some reason the `$arr` is empty for whatever reason than if you try and access `$diff` it won't be set and you will get an error. generally it is a good idea to declare all variables and arrays.